Интеграция оплаты Юкасса и Телеграм-бота на Java
Подскажите, кто интегрировал Юкассу и Телеграм-бота на Java,
делаю следующее:
 public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        ...
        if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
           startMethod(update, command, userId);
        } else if (update.hasPreCheckoutQuery()) {
            PreCheckoutQuery preCheckoutQuery = update.getPreCheckoutQuery();

        AnswerPreCheckoutQuery answer = new AnswerPreCheckoutQuery();
        answer.setPreCheckoutQueryId(preCheckoutQuery.getId());// Если true, то оплата прошла успешно

        answer.setOk(true);
        try {
            execute(answer);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Далее метод startMethod():
private void startMethod(Update update, Message command, long userId) {
        String messageText = update.getMessage().getText();
        switch (messageText) {
            case "/start":
                ...
                break;
            case "Оплата":
                long chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();
                // Создание массива items
                JSONArray items = new JSONArray();

                JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
                item.put("description", "Товар 1");
                item.put("quantity", 1);

                JSONObject amount = new JSONObject();
                amount.put("value", "100.00");
                amount.put("currency", "RUB");

                item.put("amount", amount);
                items.put(item);

                // Заполнение providerData
                JSONObject providerData = new JSONObject();
                providerData.put("order_number", "123456");
                providerData.put("items", items);

                // Создаем инвойс

                SendInvoice invoice = new SendInvoice();
                invoice.setChatId(chatId);
                invoice.setProviderData(String.valueOf(providerData));
//                invoice.setProviderData("{\"receipt\": {\"items\": [{\"description\": \"Название товара\", \"quantity\": \"1\", \"amount\": {\"value\": \"100.00\", \"currency\": \"RUB\"}, \"vat_code\": 1}], \"email\": \"mail@mail.ru\"}})");
                invoice.setNeedName(true);
                invoice.setNeedEmail(true);
                invoice.setSendEmailToProvider(true);
                invoice.setNeedPhoneNumber(true);
                invoice.setSendPhoneNumberToProvider(true);
                invoice.setTitle("Тест");
                invoice.setDescription("Описание");
                invoice.setPayload("Бот"); // Уникальный идентификатор платежа
                invoice.setProviderToken("******:LIVE:*****");
                invoice.setStartParameter("start");
                invoice.setCurrency("RUB");
                List<LabeledPrice> prices = new ArrayList<>();
                prices.add(new LabeledPrice("Покупка товара", 10000)); // Цена указана в копейках
                invoice.setPrices(prices);   
                try {
                    execute(invoice);
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            default:
                ...
                break;
        }
    }

В итоге форма создается:

Заполняем все данные, в том числе данные карты, и нажимаем оплатить:

Он думает и пишет "Время ожидания.. что-то там, Деньги не будут списаны." - или как-то так.
Прошу помочь.
